# sql- create a directory like structure from links

Tags: mysql, sql, url, substring, concatenation

I have a table with column containing many URLs of various files, I want to create a directory like structure, folders and files sort of.

**Folders first, then files**

```
links
----------
http://abcd.com/efgh/hhg.txt
http://abcd.com/efgh/abc/bsbs/hsgs.txt
http://abcd.com/lmn.txt
http://abcd.com/jhksdh/khsdh/khd/abc.txt
http://abcd.com/dsfsdh/khsdh/dsfsdf/bsbs.txt
```

when entered `http://abcd.com/` in query it should produce

```
╔════╦═════════════════╗
║    ║                 ║
╠════╬═════════════════╣
║  1 ║ efgh            ║
║  2 ║ jhksdh          ║
║  3 ║ dsfsdh          ║
║  4 ║ lmn.txt         ║
╚════╩═════════════════╝
```

when entered `http://abcd.com/efgh/` in query it should produce

```
╔════╦═════════════════╗
║    ║                 ║
╠════╬═════════════════╣
║  1 ║ abc             ║
║  2 ║ hhg.txt         ║
╚════╩═════════════════╝
```

I can't make up a query using SUBSTRING_INDEX() string function

Comment: Why do you need regex? Do you want to get all these results when a url is fired?

Comment: substring can work too @learner

Answer (score 1):

Is this close enough to what you want?

```
select l.*
from links l
where l.link like concat(@link, '/%')
```

I ask, because usually such a table would often (properly?) have all levels as separate rows.  So, `links` would have rows for:

```
http://abcd.com/efgh/abc/bsbs/hsgs.txt
http://abcd.com/efgh/abc/bsbs
http://abcd.com/efgh/abc
http://abcd.com/efgh
http://abcd.com
http://
```

Then the following query does what you want:

```
select l.*
from links l
where l.link like concat(@link, '/%') and
      l.link not like concat(@link, '/%/%');
```

Without changing the data, this would generally work:

```
select concat(@link, '/',
              substring_index(substring(@link, length(@link) + 1
                                       ),
                              '/', 1
                             )
             )
from links l
where l.link like concat(@link, '/%');
```

Comment: it doesn't have all levels as separate rows, it contains all direct links

Comment: Which one should i use? Error is coming in all of them

Comment: This is coming from third one :

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 1))
from table l
where l.link like concat('http://abcd.com' at line 1

Comment: @Azhar . . . There doesn't appear to be an (obvious) error near `1))` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
set @param = 'http://abcd.com/efgh/';
select 
distinct SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(link, @param, ''), '/', 1) as link 
from links 
where POSITION(@param IN link) > 0;
```